# Org-mode headings in multiple places at once? (transclusion)

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to organize my headings in multiple ways at once. (with the same degree of flexibility that I have when organizing things in any one place - e.g. more than the Agenda provides)

Ideally I'd be able to make a heading in part of a document, and then create a "hard link" to the heading somewhere else, which would update both as the content of heading changed.

Next best would be "soft links" which only store the heading content in one canonical location, and just show it in the other location (and if you edit it in either, it just updates in the canonical location).

Right now the best I know how to do is just create normal links, which I need to manually follow to see the content. Is there any way to do better than this?

Comment: If you are talking about using the same heading at multiple places and not the content under that heading,  you can use the **org-mode macros** for that.

Comment: I'd like the content under the heading too if possible. Macros though only seem to help with export (according to https://github.com/fniessen/org-macros). I'd like to just have the headings essentially auto-synced (or editing remotely) during normal usage, so I can navigate them just like any other org text (and see them in agendas etc.).

Comment: Can you provide an example because I don't yet understand the use case.

Comment: This is slightly contrived for simplicity. I sometimes organize a projects pending tasks into a "hierarchal view," and a "task order" view. The hierarchal view breaks down tasks (headings), into subtask dependencies (subheadings, etc.). The "task order" view shows tasks by the partial order of when they should be completed (which doesn't follow the hierarchy, except to satisfy dependencies). I'd like to be able to change a task in one "view" and have it change in the other "view." I know something similar can be done with agendas/tags/timestamps but it doesn't satisfy other criteria.

Comment: I haven't used [`org-copy`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-copy.html) but that probably could be the solution. Maybe someone using that can provide their input on this.

Comment: `org-copy` on its own just copies a heading to a new location - it won't update copies as they change.

Comment: This provides a very limited partial solution, but perhaps something like it could be adapted into a full solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328515/iso-transclusion-in-emacs-org-mode . I also just changed the title to include the keyword transclusion.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the information, would you consider using a custom agenda view with a sorting strategy to get your task order view instead?

Comment: It's possible that one could do something relatedly useful with the agenda system for that specific case, but the agenda view and the normal org editing environment allow very different interactions, so the result would be very different. I think that would be an interesting separate question, but doesn't address my core concern here.

Comment: I would be glad with a weaker solution. Can we get ,e.g , a dynamic block to display a heading from another file. something like `#+BEGIN: my-include :file file :heading heading` `#+END:`?  That is, similar to `#+INCLUDE: "file::#heading" :only-contents t` but *live*. I bet we can have some not too complicated elisp code to do that. unfortunatelly my elisp skills are minimal, at best, it will take me a loong time to understand if it really is possible. Maybe someone can pick it up?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I don't have the 'rep' to comment on the thread above yet. I'm looking for something like this too, here's where I got up to: This looks pretty awesome but is apparently un-installable and unmaintained by the author (who still uses it themselves though)
https://github.com/gregdetre/emacs-freex This is supposed to be a minimalist version of the above using what I guess is dynamic blocks but also WIP, haven't tried it yet.
https://github.com/whacked/transclusion-minor-mode

Answer (score 2):

There is a minor mode that provides transclusion https://github.com/whacked/transclusion-minor-mode which I think is exactly what you are looking for.