# How to expand external files inline on orgmode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-link

I know I can use something like `#+INCLUDE: "./filepath"` but this has effect only when I export the file. I can also use link like `[[./filepath]]` but I have to type `C-c C-o` to go to the content.

How to automatically expand this `include` or this link to the current file? It is useful to use `C-s` (ISearch) and other practical things like edit the external content inline without change buffer or window.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I know I can type `C-x i` to insert a content of any file inside my current org file, but it isn't what I really want. I want a two-way direct link between my current org file and external files. If I modify the external file, my current org file is automatically updated. And vice-versa.

My current application is: I have a file called `mapmind.org` where I have my map mind. I use the tool [org-mind-map](https://github.com/theodorewiles/org-mind-map) to export this into a beautiful diagram. Unfortunately this tool doesn't allow to export only a region, so this should be in a single separated file. And I have my main org file, called `main.org`. I have several items and one of them is:

```
* Map mind
See [[./mapmind.org]].
#+INCLUDE mapmind.org
```

When I export the entire file into a PDF, for example, I can see my mapmind there. If I put the cursor above the link, I can navigate using `C-c C-o`, or I can go to file using `C-c '` above include line as John Kitchin said as commentary. But this is very unpractical because search commands like `C-s`, `C-r` and so on does't find anything in `mapmind.org` file. Also, I'd like to see and edit the content directly in my main org file without the need to navigate elsewhere.

This feature could be useful for many other applications.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want. You can type C-c ' on the include line to open the file, and then do what you want in it.  If you want to insert the contents of a file, you can type C-x i to insert it, but then the resulting text is not connected to the file anymore.

Comment: It is feasible but requires some serious elisp skills. One can create a new buffer (as alternative view of the master org file) and combine regions of several files there with [multifile.el](https://github.com/magnars/multifiles.el). The regions are editable, searchable, and so on. Modifications of the view buffer are also applied to the original buffers. `org-mode` can be activated in the view buffer. I've got a calendar consisting of one org-file per day. I use a similar method to create a view on a certain topic in the files of that calendar spanning several days.

Comment: @JohnKitchin I think you actually didn't understand. I edited to try to be more clear. But what I want is show the content in the original buffer linked and updated in "real time" to an external org file. If I modify the file externally, the content is automatically updated, and if I modify the file inside my buffer, the file is modified externally as well.

Comment: You might find some inspiration at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12562/org-mode-headings-in-multiple-places-at-once-transclusion. Otherwise I think you can do what @Tobias suggested.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328515/iso-transclusion-in-emacs-org-mode

Comment: Did you try [`transclusion-minor-mode`](https://github.com/whacked/transclusion-minor-mode) as John Kitchin suggested? What was the outcome?

Comment: I didn't try it yet because it is a "work in progress" project and it doesn't looks so straightforward. But I'll try this soon if I don't find any better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays this is possible using the [org-transclusion](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion) package!

After installing it, write this in a file in Org mode:

```
#+transclude: [[path-to-external-file]]
```

Then `M-x org-transclusion-mode` and the contents appear, are searchable, and editable (by pressing `e`) from the original Org file.

Comment: This is amazing!